# How do I list all applications that are contained in a docker container?

Tags: docker

I have downloaded a docker container that performs several different operations on an input file using several different kinds of software, i.e. alignment, variant calling etc. How do I find out what the contents of the docker container/image is? Sorry if this is trivial I am totally new to docker.

Comment: Do you need to see directory structure? Or list of installed packages?

Answer (score 29):

There are (at least) three ways to interpret your question:

- *which packages* are installed in the container;
- *what files* are there: explore container's *filesystem*;
- what [*images and layers*](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/#images-and-layers) does the container consist of?

## 1. List *packages* installed in container

The way to get list of installed packages depends on distribution. There are three most popular families:

- Alpine, lightweight Linux distribution based on musl and BusyBox
- Debian-based (Debian, Ubuntu)
- rpm-based (RHEL, CentOS and Fedora)

#### Alpine-based containers

Use `apk info -vv` command:

```bash
docker exec -i <container_id_1>  apk info -vv | sort
```

#### Debian & Ubuntu  - based containers

Use `dpkg -l` command:

```bash
docker exec -i <container_id_1>  dpkg -l
```

#### RHEL, CentOS and Fedora - based containers

Use `rpm -qa` or `yum list installed` command:

```bash
docker exec -i <container_id_1>  rpm -qa
docker exec -i <container_id_1>  yum list installed
```

## 2. Explore container's *filesystem*

To see directory structure you can use either `bash` & `tree` or cool tools developed specially for exploring docker images

### `tree`

```bash
docker exec -i <container_id_1> tree /
```

**Note**: not all images contain `tree` command.

### `docker export` with `tar`

`docker export adoring_kowalevski > contents.tar`
And then, tou can explore `contents.tar` with your preferred archiver. I.e. for `tar`:

`tar -tvf contents.tar`

## 3. Special tools (explore *images and layers* `OverlayFS`)

#### wagoodman/dive

[wagoodman/dive: A tool for exploring each layer in a docker image](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive)

```
docker run --rm -it \ 
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  wagoodman/dive:latest \
  <image_name|image_id>
```

> A tool for exploring a docker image, layer contents, and discovering ways to shrink your Docker image size.
> [image]

#### tomastomecek/sen

[TomasTomecek/sen: Terminal User Interface for docker engine](https://github.com/TomasTomecek/sen)

`docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/run/docker.sock -ti -e TERM tomastomecek/sen`

> it can interactively manage your containers and images:
> [image]

#### justone/dockviz

[justone/dockviz: Visualizing Docker data](https://github.com/justone/dockviz)

`$ dockviz containers -d -r | dot -Tpng -o containers.png`

> Containers are visualized with labelled lines for links. Containers that aren't running are greyed out.
>
> ```
> $ dockviz containers -d -r | dot -Tpng -o containers.png
> ```
>
> [image]

Answer (score 2):

You can get information concerning the image by using:
`docker image inspect <image>` and `docker image history <image>` and then if you want to get information concerning the container, simply enter in the running container using exec command `docker container exec -itu 0 <container> /bin/bash`(pay attention your container may be using another shell)  and afterward just gather the needed information (os, running processes, open files, etc)

More information about exec command: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/.

PS: To list images `docker image ls` , to list running containers `docker container ps`

Answer (score 2):

Since Docker Desktop 4.7.0 you can use the [experimental `sbom` command](https://www.docker.com/blog/announcing-docker-sbom-a-step-towards-more-visibility-into-docker-images/) to get the "Software Bill of Rights", which is a pretty comprehensive list of all contained libraries and corresponding versions. E.g.

```
$ docker sbom openjdk:11-jre-slim-buster
Syft v0.43.0
 ✔ Pulled image
 ✔ Loaded image
 ✔ Parsed image
 ✔ Cataloged packages      [91 packages]

NAME                    VERSION                  TYPE
adduser                 3.118                    deb
apt                     1.8.2.3                  deb
base-files              10.3+deb10u12            deb
base-passwd             3.5.46                   deb
bash                    5.0-4                    deb
bsdutils                1:2.33.1-0.1             deb
ca-certificates         20200601~deb10u2         deb
coreutils               8.30-3                   deb
dash                    0.5.10.2-5               deb
debconf                 1.5.71+deb10u1           deb
debian-archive-keyring  2019.1+deb10u1           deb
[...]
```

As you can see it's based on [Syft](https://github.com/anchore/syft) which is third party tool. That may change in the future though (hence experimental). In fact you can also use Syft directly so you don't need Docker Desktop.