# Laravel Dockerfile > 1GB

Tags: php, laravel, docker, overlayfs

I'm building a `Docker` Image for my `Laravel` application but it's getting bigger than `1GB`.
This is the `Dockerfile`:

```
#
# PHP Dependencies
#
FROM composer as vendor

COPY database/ database/
COPY composer.json composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.lock

RUN composer install \
    --ignore-platform-reqs \
    --no-interaction \
    --no-plugins \
    --no-scripts \
    --prefer-dist

#
# Application
#
FROM php:fpm-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        $PHPIZE_DEPS \
        curl \
        libtool \
        libxml2-dev \
    && apk add --no-cache \
        curl \
        git \
        mysql-client \
    && pecl install redis \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        pdo \
        pdo_mysql \
        tokenizer \
        bcmath \
        opcache \
        xml \
    && apk del -f .build-deps \
    && docker-php-ext-enable \
       pdo_mysql \
       redis

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY . /var/www/html
COPY --from=vendor /app/vendor/ /var/www/html/vendor/
COPY .env.staging /var/www/html/.env

RUN chown -R root:www-data . 

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

I use `Vue` as front-end and `Redis` as caching provider.

I am used to images around the 200-300 MBs but this is ridiculous.

What can I do to reduce the image size?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing exactly what you're copying into that container and what dependencies you have in your composer.json files, but have you considered using [Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#choose-the--v-or---mount-flag)? Are you using this image strictly for Development purposes? Or do you plan on deploying it somewhere like Kubernetes or an ECS service?

Comment: `docker history` will give you some hints as to which specific Dockerfile step is taking up space; you should also be able to run commands like `du` (for example `docker run --rm yourimage du -k /usr`) to see where space is going.

Comment: What have you tried to find the cause for that size? How **exactly** did you measure the size?

Answer (score 1):

Since `docker` filesystem is [`OverlayFS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OverlayFS), you need a special tool to dive into FS layers.

There are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57804009/5720818) tools to explore images. 
For your case I'd suggest [`wagoodman/dive`](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive): A tool for exploring each layer in a docker image

```
docker run --rm -it \ 
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  wagoodman/dive:latest \
  <image_name|image_id>
```

> A tool for exploring a docker image, layer contents, and discovering ways to shrink your Docker image size. [image]

As you can see on the screenshot - `Layers` table has `Size` column.

So, you can find - which layer of your `docker` image has the greatest contribution to the volume of the final image.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - how does this tool reduce the size of an image?